# Should I remove Adult Dependent from my 2019 tax return so they will receive a COVID Stimulus Check?

Tags: united-states, dependents, amended-tax-return, stimulus, covid-19

On my 2019 Tax Return I claimed my 28 year old girlfriend as a dependent. This makes her ineligible to receive a COVID Stimulus Check. My return was already accepted and I have already received my refund. Should I amend my return, remove her as a dependent? Would she then be eligible to receive the stimulus check?

Answer (score 6):

You choosing to remove her as your dependent, or you choosing to not have claimed her as your dependent in the first place when you filed, will not allow her to get the stimulus payment. The restriction is that she cannot get the stimulus payment if she *can be* claimed by somebody else as a dependent, not that she actually was claimed by somebody else as a dependent. The fact that you have a choice to claim her as your dependent or not, implies that she *can be* claimed by you as a dependent (i.e. she meets the conditions in the law to qualify as your dependent). In that case, she cannot get the stimulus payment, even if you do not actually claim her as a dependent on your tax return.