# Stimulus and adult parental dependent claimed for 2019

Tags: united-states, dependents, amended-tax-return, covid-19, stimulus

Can I amend my 2019 return to remove my parent as a dependent so they can get stimulus check?  I know that it says that if an adult "can" be claimed as a dependent than they aren't eligible but how does the IRS know if an adult could be claimed or not be claimed as an adult dependent on someone's tax return regarding the COVID stimulus?

Comment: Are you asking how to commit tax fraud? Does this answer your question? [Should I remove Adult Dependent from my 2019 tax return so they will receive a COVID Stimulus Check?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/123277/should-i-remove-adult-dependent-from-my-2019-tax-return-so-they-will-receive-a-c)

Comment: Roughly speaking, the income requirements to file are less than the income requirements to be claimed as a dependent. Even if someone claims you as a dependent, you may still need to file a return, and if your income is so low that you *don't* need to file a return, you aren't in need of a stimulus payment. (Put another way, the current situation *hasn't* had an economic impact on you personally.)

Comment: @chepner: And yet Social Security recipients, who haven't been economically impacted, do receive the payment.  The payment is an economic stimulus not replacement of lost income (although CARES also boosted unemployment insurance). The fact that it phases out at higher income levels just adds to the confusion.

Comment: True, I missed the distinction I was trying to make (if it's even clear to me *what* that distinction is).